# How to access my ASP.NET Web API on Windows Azure VM from the outside world?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-virtual-machine

I have a ASP.NET web API running on an Azure Windows VM. I use .rdp file remote desktop to access my VM and transfer archive/Compile code remotely on the VM.
I can access the ASP.NET web API default page on the remote desktop server at [image]

What exactly should I do in Azure network security group to access my WebAPI from the Public Static IP of my VM ?

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 8000 in the NSG.

The steps you can follow:

1. Create a network security group if you don't have one.
2. Create an inbound security rule allowing traffic and assign values to the following settings:

- **Destination port ranges**: `8000`
- **Source port ranges**: `*` (allows any source port) or your client public IP address
- **Priority value**: Enter a value that is less than 65,500 and higher in priority than the default catch-all deny inbound rule.

For example,

[image]

3. Associate the network security group with the VM network interface or subnet.

Then you may restart your Azure VM to take this effect. Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).